# remove/filter directory from list.dirs if file exists, r

Tags: r

I have a directory with lots of subdirectories. I'm using list.dirs in combination with list.files to find directories that contain a specific file. Once the file is found, I want to remove the subdirectory from the list.dirs list so I can look for different files in the remaining directories. The idea is to have the code pass through all directories looking for a file that meets the pattern I indicate in list.files, while removing the directories where the file is found from the list.dirs list of directories. Here is an example directory setup:

```
subdir1
   filea.txt
subdir2
   fileb.txt
subdir3
   filea.txt
```

I attempted writing an If statement for the existence of a file to then remove the current subdirectory from the list of directories, but have been unsuccessful:

```
subDirsPaths = list.dirs(path=".", full.names=TRUE)

for (subDirsPath in subDirsPaths){
  setwd("/home/phil/Desktop/folder")

    inFilePaths = list.files(path=".", pattern=glob2rx(print(paste("*","a.txt", sep=""))), full.names=TRUE)
    for (inFilePath in inFilePaths){

      inFilePath2 <- gsub("./", "", inFilePath)
      if (file.exists(print(paste(inFilePath2, sep=""))))
      {

        print("file exists")
        subDirsPaths <- subDirsPaths[-subDirsPath]
      } else {}

    }


  }
```

After this is ran, I want to run another

```
for(subDirsPath in subDirsPaths) {}
```

But this time only on the directories that didn't contain the files I was looking for in the previous block of code, and so on.

When I type subDirsPaths into the terminal it lists:

```
subDirsPaths

"./subdir1" "./subdir2" "./subdir3"
```

What I want after I run this code is this:

```
subDirsPaths

"./subdir2"
```

As you can see, since filea.txt was found in subdir1 and subdir3 they have been removed from the list of directories.

Comment: Would the `recurse` option in `list.files` in combination with the `full.names = TRUE` option be easier?

Comment: no because in my actual directory I have additional sub directories within these sub directories that complicate the recurse option.

Comment: not sure if I understand what you want but aren't you looking for `basename`?

Comment: I tried basename but the object is found. The list.dirs contains the ./ before the basename in the list. I'll add the desired output to the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. The problem is how I tried to remove the directory from the list of directories. The current directory is listed as subDirsPath, which I am trying to remove from my list of directories called subDirsPaths.

I initially tried to accomplish this using this statement:

```
subDirsPaths <- subDirsPaths[-subDirsPath]
```

I replaced this line with the following solution:

```
subDirsPaths <- subDirsPaths[!subDirsPaths %in% grep(paste0(subDirsPath, collapse = "|"), subDirsPaths, value = T)]
```